# Masking with 'where' using Python xarray is not working anymore

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am running into troubles after updating `xarray`.

I have a salinity dataset whose dimensions are:

```
(u'time', u'stations', u'layer')
```

For a specific station, I want to get the salinity of a chosen depth, say -10 m. The dimension layer contains the values of depth that vary with time, i.e, a given layer contains different values of depth over time (due to water level variations).

Previously I was doing the following:

```
ds.salinity.sel(stations='mystation').where( np.ceil(ds.layer(stations='mystation')) ==-10 )
```

which was working just fine.

But now I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7e83f5e839cc> in <module>()
      1 fmstation = 'T1_50'
      2 
----> 3 sal10m = ds.salinity.sel(stations = ds.stations[ds.station_name == fmstation]).where(np.ceil(ds.Zcoordinate_c.isel(stations = ds.stations[ds.station_name == fmstation])) == -10) #.mean(axis=2).plot()
      4 sal10m #.plot()

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.pyc in where(self, cond)
    481           * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4
    482         """
--> 483         return self._where(cond)
    484 
    485     # this has no runtime function - these are listed so IDEs know these methods

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataarray.pyc in func(self, other)
   1193                         if not reflexive
   1194                         else f(other_variable, self.variable))
-> 1195             coords = self.coords.merge(other_coords)._variables
   1196             name = self._result_name(other)
   1197 

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\coordinates.pyc in merge(self, other)
    139         ds = self.to_dataset()
    140         if other is not None:
--> 141             conflicts = self._merge_validate(other)
    142             _coord_merge_finalize(ds.coords, other, *conflicts)
    143         return ds

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\coordinates.pyc in _merge_validate(self, other)
     89                 self_var = self._variables[k]
     90                 other_var = other[k].variable
---> 91                 if not self_var.broadcast_equals(other_var):
     92                     if k in self.dims and k in other.dims:
     93                         raise ValueError('index %r not aligned' % k)

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.pyc in broadcast_equals(self, other)
    976         except (ValueError, AttributeError):
    977             return False
--> 978         return self.equals(other)
    979 
    980     def identical(self, other):

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.pyc in equals(self, other)
    961         other = getattr(other, 'variable', other)
    962         try:
--> 963             return (self.dims == other.dims and self._data_equals(other))
    964         except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    965             return False

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.pyc in _data_equals(self, other)
    947     def _data_equals(self, other):
    948         return (self._data is other._data or
--> 949                 ops.array_equiv(self.data, other.data))
    950 
    951     def equals(self, other):

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\ops.pyc in array_equiv(arr1, arr2)
    188     if arr1.shape != arr2.shape:
    189         return False
--> 190     return bool(((arr1 == arr2) | (isnull(arr1) & isnull(arr2))).all())
    191 
    192 

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.pyc in all(self, axis, keepdims, split_every)
   1146     def all(self, axis=None, keepdims=False, split_every=None):
   1147         from .reductions import all
-> 1148         return all(self, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims, split_every=split_every)
   1149 
   1150     @wraps(np.min)

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\reductions.pyc in all(a, axis, keepdims, split_every)
    161 def all(a, axis=None, keepdims=False, split_every=None):
    162     return reduction(a, chunk.all, chunk.all, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims,
--> 163                      dtype='bool', split_every=split_every)
    164 
    165 

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\reductions.pyc in reduction(x, chunk, aggregate, axis, keepdims, dtype, split_every, combine, name)
     42 
     43     return _tree_reduce(tmp, aggregate, axis, keepdims, dtype, split_every,
---> 44                        combine, name=name)
     45 
     46 

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\reductions.pyc in _tree_reduce(x, aggregate, axis, keepdims, dtype, split_every, combine, name)
     75     return partial_reduce(func, x, split_every, keepdims=keepdims,
     76                           dtype=dtype,
---> 77                           name=(name or funcname(aggregate)) + '-aggregate')
     78 
     79 

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\reductions.pyc in partial_reduce(func, x, split_every, keepdims, dtype, name)
    105         out_axis = [i for i in range(x.ndim) if i not in split_every]
    106         getter = lambda k: get(out_axis, k)
--> 107         keys = map(getter, keys)
    108         out_chunks = list(getter(out_chunks))
    109     dsk = {}

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\dask\array\reductions.pyc in <lambda>(k)
    104     if not keepdims:
    105         out_axis = [i for i in range(x.ndim) if i not in split_every]
--> 106         getter = lambda k: get(out_axis, k)
    107         keys = map(getter, keys)
    108         out_chunks = list(getter(out_chunks))

C:\Users\Smeirellesnune\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\toolz\itertoolz.pyc in get(ind, seq, default)
    374                     return operator.itemgetter(*ind)(seq)
    375                 else:
--> 376                     return (seq[ind[0]],)
    377             else:
    378                 return tuple(_get(i, seq, default) for i in ind)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Does someone know what is going on here?**

**Or is there any smarter way to slice my dataset?**

The xarray version I am using is:

> xarray 0.7.2

sys.version:

```
'2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

**EDIT: ADDED DATASET DETAILS**

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                              (cross_section: 15, cross_section_pts: 3, laydim: 20, laydimw: 21, stations: 979, time: 2512)
Coordinates:
    station_x_coordinate                 (stations) float64 4.194 4.008 ...
    station_y_coordinate                 (stations) float64 52.07 51.99 52.0 ...
    station_name                         (stations) |S64 'zmBoei_wav' ...
    Zcoordinate_c                        (time, stations, laydim) float64 -10.98 ...
    Zcoordinate_w                        (time, stations, laydimw) float64 -11.28 ...
    cross_section_name                   (cross_section) |S64 'L1' 'L2' 'L3' ...
  * time                                 (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-10-02T06:00:00 ...
  * cross_section                        (cross_section) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
  * cross_section_pts                    (cross_section_pts) int64 0 1 2
  * laydim                               (laydim) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  * laydimw                              (laydimw) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  * stations                             (stations) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
Data variables:
    station_id                           (stations) |S64 'zmBoei_wav' ...
    waterlevel                           (time, stations) float64 0.6178 ...
    Waterdepth                           (time, stations) float64 11.9 20.36 ...
    x_velocity                           (time, stations, laydim) float64 0.1941 ...
    y_velocity                           (time, stations, laydim) float64 0.0954 ...
    z_velocity                           (time, stations, laydim) float64 0.000392 ...
    Tke                                  (time, stations, laydimw) float64 1e-32 ...
    Eps                                  (time, stations, laydimw) float64 1e-32 ...
    Vicww                                (time, stations, laydimw) float64 0.0 ...
    salinity                             (time, stations, laydim) float64 26.26 ...
    cross_section_x_coordinate           (cross_section, cross_section_pts) float64 4.206 ...
    cross_section_y_coordinate           (cross_section, cross_section_pts) float64 51.94 ...
    cross_section_discharge              (time, cross_section) float64 0.0 ...
    cross_section_area                   (time, cross_section) float64 8.762e+03 ...
    cross_section_velocity               (time, cross_section) float64 0.0 ...
    cross_section_salt                   (time, cross_section) float64 -1.142e+05 ...
    WaterBalance_total_volume            (time) float64 0.0 1.227e+11 ...
    WaterBalance_storage                 (time) float64 0.0 1.227e+11 ...
    WaterBalance_volume_error            (time) float64 0.0 -1.499e+07 ...
    WaterBalance_boundaries_in           (time) float64 0.0 3.827e+08 ...
    WaterBalance_boundaries_out          (time) float64 0.0 6.048e+07 ...
    WaterBalance_boundaries_total        (time) float64 0.0 3.222e+08 ...
    WaterBalance_exchange_with_1D_in     (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    WaterBalance_exchange_with_1D_out    (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    WaterBalance_exchange_with_1D_total  (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    WaterBalance_precipitation           (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    WaterBalance_source_sink             (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
Attributes:
    institution: Deltares
    references: http://www.deltares.nl
    source: Deltares, D-Flow FM Version 1.1.182.45395, Apr 07 2016, 10:16:58, model
    history: Created on 2016-05-23T21:50:20+0200, D-Flow FM
    date_created: 2016-05-23T21:50:20+0200
    date_modified: 2016-05-23T21:50:20+0200
    Conventions: CF-1.5 Deltares-0.1
```

Comment: Great first question, welcome to the site!

Comment: This looks odd: `ds.stations[ds.station_name == fmstation]`.Which will evaluate to `ds.stations[True]` or `ds.stations[False]` which, in turn, will evaluate to `ds.stations[1] or [ds.stations[0]`.

Comment: Can you share what your dataset looks like when printed? This is likely a bug in xarray or dask that occurs with particular types or shapes of data.

Comment: The code in your question and the code in the traceback is not the same. Why not?

Comment: @Stephan, I sorted it out the problem by installing the [IOOS](https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes) package together with [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/#). As I layman, I am not quite of what was going on before. Do you still want to dig into it?

Comment: @HåkenLid, you're right. I changed for the sake of simplicity but the idea is the same.

Comment: @s_meirelles Can you post the traceback you get when you run the line in your question instead. When the code and the traceback don't match it's very hard for us to figure out what your actual problem is.

Comment: If this worked when you used packages from the IOOS channel, then this was probably a bug in dask that has been already fixed, so I think we can consider this resolved. (Note that the generic "conda-forge" channel should be preferred to IOOS now.)

Comment: @HåkenLid the code line in my question is just a generic line that I thought it would be a didactic way to show my problem. The actual line was this: `ds.salinity.sel(stations = ds.stations[ds.station_name == fmstation]).where(np.ceil(ds.Zcoordinate_c.isel(stations = ds.stations[ds.station_name == fmstation])) == -10)`.  And the traceback is that on the original post.

Comment: @Stephan, I am a newbie here. Shall you write down the solution then I can accept it?

Comment: @s_meirelles: You can also submit an answer yourself and accept it. That can be helpful for people who find this question later by search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the packages from the IOOS channel together with dask solved the problem. For setting up the IOOS Python environment follow the steps at:

https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes/wiki/Setting-up-the-IOOS-Python-environment

As @Stephan pointed out: *the generic "conda-forge" channel should be preferred to IOOS now.* Learn more at:

https://conda-forge.github.io/

Secondly, install dask as following:

```
conda install dask -c conda-forge
```

Activate IOOS before starting up Python:

```
source activate IOOS #(OSX and Linux)
activate IOOS #(Windows)
```